# Run batch script showing output & recording output to a file

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting

I know `cmd > file.txt` to record an output of a command to a file in Windows!.

Does anybody know how to run a batch script recording the output to a file AND also showing the output on the command prompt as well when executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a Windows-based implementation of `tee` to do this.  Here are some options:

- [`wintee`](http://code.google.com/p/wintee/) stand-alone utility
- [GnuWin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) Gnu for Win32

If you don't require output *in situ*, you can "cheat" by piping the commands, but this is not nearly as useful as following stdout in real-time.

`cmd >file.txt | type file.txt`

Comment: I thought of using your easy method `cmd >file.txt | type file.txt` but it's showing the copy percentage as 0%(not updating) till the end. I'm trying to install `wintee`, didn't get correct link yet. Trying...

Comment: @user53864 Yes, the redirection+pipe doesn't work quite like `tee`, as the first command must complete *entirely* before the `type` will occur. The code.google.com link in my answer is a working version of `wintee` -- is it non-functional for you?

Comment: That `wintee.exe` just opening and staying like a statue when I double clicked to execute it.

Comment: @user53864 It is a command-line program, not a windowed one.  Try `wtee.exe --help` for usage. Using your question's example, you'd want to do `cmd | wtee.exe file.txt` to see the output on stdout as well as redirect it to `file.txt`.

Comment: Oh...no. Actually I was using `cmd | tee file.txt` instead of `cmd | wtee file.txt`. That was my mistake which you corrected it. I thought I should install wtee.exe file by double clicking it but as you said it's not and instead should directly place it under system32. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

How about `mtee`?

[mtee](http://www.commandline.co.uk/mtee/)

This looks most appealing to me...

`script.cmd | mtee result.%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.log`

The result log will have *YYYYMMDD* format.

If you want to include time with the log, you can also include this:

%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% (*HHmm*)

p.s. I just noticed that if the time is AM there is a space in the file name, so you will need to wrap mtee log file in double quotes to generate the correct file name.